# Extracting text using sed does not work as expected

Tags: sed, awk

I am just starting out using `sed` and I intend to use it to extract IP addresses from `ping` output. Here's what I am trying to achieve exactly:

input text:

```
ytmti (192.188.2.3) jjggy
```

desired output:

```
192.188.2.3
```

command I am trying:

```
echo "ytmti (192.188.2.3) jjggy" | sed 's:\((\(192.188.2.3\))\):\2:'
```

current output:

```
ytmti 192.188.2.3 jjggy
```

Note: `ytmti` and `jjggy` are really stand-ins for text like `Pinging unix.stackexchange.com` and `with 32 bytes of data:`.

I think using `awk` might be a better solution for parsing `ping` output,
but I would like to get accustomed to `sed`.

Comment: Please note that `Note:...etc` above was inserted by others and does not accurately reflect the question as it was first asked. Whether it accurately reflects op's original intent i cannot say, but it was certainly added after the question was asked. Please see [this meta question](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2992/how-was-my-suggested-edit-not-useful) about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The substitution command of `sed` replaces all characters matched in first section with all character of second section, so you will need `.*` or similar and group only the part to save, like:

```
echo " ytmti (192.188.2.3) jjggy" | sed 's:^.*(\([^)]*\).*$:\1:'
```

Note that I use `[^)]*` that avoids to hardcode the IP and generalize it for any of them. It yields:

```
192.188.2.3
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the field seperator variable in `awk`:

```
echo "ytmti (192.188.2.3) jjggy" | awk -F'[)(]' '{print $2}'                                                                                              
192.188.2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
echo 'ytmti (192.188.2.3) jjggy' | tr -dc '0-9.'
```

Comment: Read the question: “I … intend to use [sed] to extract IP addresses from ping output.” The output from `ping` commonly begins with a line something like `Pinging unix.stackexchange.com (198.252.206.140) with 32 bytes of data:`. Your answer includes in the output (a) the `32`, (b) the `.`s in the domain name, and (c) any numerals that happen to be in the domain name.

Comment: @Scott - I did read the question, though I am afraid you may not have. I think you must have missed the part of the question wherein op says: *I am trying: echo " ytmti (192.188.2.3) jjggy"*. Still, it matters not. This was never intended as a practical example for how to render *any* data into an ip address, but merely as an example of what one or another tool might do with a certain example set. And so you are free to believe whatever nonsense makes you most comfortable.

Comment: @mikeserv while I definitely appreciate your effort, the other answers are much more useful overall since they take into account the fact that I will eventually want to extract an IP from ping.

Comment: @user293496 we're agreed. It wasn't intended to be very practical - just to give you or anyone else an idea that there are always several ways to work through a sample set. I didn't really expect the one upvote it's got...